# How to lock LabelText in OutlinedTextField?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a header for an OutlinedTextField field. He show up. only when I click on the field and start typing. Is there a way to fix my label so that the position always stays on top?

**When the user starts typing:**
[image]

**When the user doesn't type anything:**
[image]

**I want to always have only the first version**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need cursor on the `OutlinedTextField`, FocusRequester will help you

```
val focusRequester = FocusRequester()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
```

and then apply it to your `OutlinedTextField` as  `Modifier .focusRequester(focusRequester)`